# C#/JSON - TypeNameHandling only when SerializationBinder is triggered

Tags: c#, json

Here is my code:

```
string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
    SerializationBinder = new CharacterDataSerializationBinder()
});
```

Here is my CharacterDataSerializationBinder:

```
public class CharacterDataSerializationBinder : ISerializationBinder
{
    DefaultSerializationBinder defaultBinder = new DefaultSerializationBinder();

    void ISerializationBinder.BindToName(Type serializedType, out string assemblyName, out string typeName)
    {
        switch (serializedType.Name)
        {
            case "CharacterData":
                assemblyName = "CharacterData";
                typeName = serializedType.Name;
                break;                
            case "Rage":
                assemblyName = "Rage";
                typeName = serializedType.Name;
                break;                
            case "Mana":
                assemblyName = "Mana";
                typeName = serializedType.Name;
                break;
            default:
                defaultBinder.BindToName(serializedType, out assemblyName, out typeName);
                break;
        }
    }

    Type ISerializationBinder.BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        switch (assemblyName)
        {
            case "CharacterData":
                return typeof(CharacterData);                
            case "Rage":
                return typeof(Rage);                
            case "Mana":
                return typeof(Mana);
            default:
                return defaultBinder.BindToType(assemblyName, typeName);
        }
    }
}
```

When I trigger `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` with `TypeNameHandling.Auto` it places type name hinting before all classes. However what I need it is to trigger TypeNameHandling only if the class is one of the  described in `ISerializationBinder.BindToName`. I hope I make my idea clear.

Is that even possible and how ?

Comment: Can you share a [mcve]?  Ordinarily `TypeNameHandling.Auto` only places type hints when the actual type of an object differs from the expected, declared type.

Comment: But checking the [source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/666d9760719e5ec5b2a50046f7dbd6a1267c01c6/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs#L997), `JsonSerializerInternalWriter.ShouldWriteType()` decides whether to write a `$type` property by checking the actual vs expected type as well as `TypeNameHandling` flags that can be applied at various levels.  There doesn't seem to be a runtime callback to decide whether to write the type.  Returning `null` from `BindToName()` doesn't help, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/ld5BaB.